# Task.WhenAll inside For Loop

Tags: multithreading, task, azure-cosmosdb, bulkinsert

I'm using `CosmosDB` along with `Azure Functions`. Here I've one long-running activity, processing Store's transactions. There are around 3000 stores and each store is having 27 million transactional records.
I'm reading the data store-by-store, performing some arithmetic operations over data, and saving the calculated data (result) in another Cosmos container.

Here's my code to :

```
 var distinctStores = _storeContainer
.Where(d => d.CreatedDate >= _yesterday.Date && d.CreatedDate < _today.Date)
.DistinctBy(x => x.LocationId)
.Select(s => s.LocationId);

try
{
   foreach (var store in distinctStores) // looping 3000 Stores here
   {
        var data = store.Transactions // It has around 27 millions data collection.

        // Here I'm doing all Calculations over data.
        // Getting the results from the calculation
        var result = getCalculatedData(data);            

        // Save the result to the container.
        var Save(result)
        
   }
}

private bool Save(List<MyModel> list)
{
   _storeDataRepo.AddBulkAsync(list);
}
```

Here's my Repository Service to store the data in Cosmos DB Container.

```
public async Task AddBulkAsync(List<TEntity> documents)
{
   List<Task> concurrentTasks = new();
   foreach (var item in documents)
   {
       concurrentTasks.Add(_container.CreateItemAsync<TEntity>(item);
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
}
```

I bit worried about calling `_storeDataRepo.AddBulkAsync(list)` inside the loop of stores. Which in turn executes `await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks)` for every loop.

Is it a better solution? please advise and help me with better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool Save(List<MyModel> list)
{
   _storeDataRepo.AddBulkAsync(list);
}
```

`AddBulkAsync` is an `async` method, you should not do this. This is firing the Async task in the background (Fire and Forget pattern) and not waiting for it.

```
private Task SaveAsync(List<MyModel> list)
{
   return _storeDataRepo.AddBulkAsync(list);
}
```

or:

```
private async Task SaveAsync(List<MyModel> list)
{
   await _storeDataRepo.AddBulkAsync(list);
}
```

And called as:

```
foreach (var store in distinctStores) // looping 3000 Stores here
   {
        var data = store.Transactions // It has around 27 millions data collection.

        // Here I'm doing all Calculations over data.
        // Getting the results from the calculation
        var result = getCalculatedData(data);            

        // Save the result to the container.
        await SaveAsync(result)
        
   }
```

Because the Bulk write does not really care if the operations are for the same store, you could just have 1 SaveAsync call with all the data from all stores:

```
List<TEntity> documents = new List<TEntity>();
foreach (var store in distinctStores) // looping 3000 Stores here
   {
        var data = store.Transactions // It has around 27 millions data collection.

        // Here I'm doing all Calculations over data.
        // Getting the results from the calculation
        var result = getCalculatedData(data);            

        // Add to the documents mean to be saved
        documents.AddRange(result);
        
   }

await SaveAsync(documents);
```